# Searching matrices in Mathematica 8 - Trying to find other elements on the same row as X

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, physics, chemistry

The text in italics describes my general goal, if anyone is interested. Question is underneath.

*I am trying to graph the energy levels of simple molecules using Mathematica 8. My method is crude, and goes as this:*

1. *Find eigenvalues of simple Hückel matrix.*
2. *Delete duplicates and determine size of list.*
3. *Evaluate the number of degeneracies by comparing duplicate list with no-duplicate list.*
4. *Create a n x 2 zero matrix where n is the number of unique energy levels.*

**5. Fill first column with unique energy levels, second column with degeneracies.**

The matrix generated in step 5 can look like this:

```
(1  2)
(3  1)   ==    M
(-1 1)
```

I wish to evaluate the maximum of column 2, and then find the value of the element in the same row, but in column 1. In this case, the answer I am looking for is 1.

These commands both evaluate to -1:

```
Extract[M[[All, 1]], M[[Max[M[[All, 2]]], 1]]]
M[[Max[M[[All, 1]]], 1]]
```

which is not the answer I want.

Any tips?

EDIT: This

```
Part[Part[Position[M, Max[M[[All, 2]]]], 1], 1]
```

works, but I don't understand *why* I have to use Part[] twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner `Part` gives you the first occurance of the maximum. `Position` returns a list of positions, even if there is only one element that has the maximum value, like this:

```
 M = {{2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 2}, {1, 1}}

 {{2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 2}, {1, 1}}

Position[M, Max[M[[All, 2]]]]

 {{2, 2}}
```

So you want the first element in the first element of this output. You could condense your code like this:

```
Position[M, Max[M[[All, 2]]]][[1, 1]]
```

However, one thing that I think your code needs to handle better is this case:

```
 M = {{3, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 2}, {1, 1}}

3, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 2}, {1, 1}}

Position[M, Max[M[[All, 2]]]]

{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}
```

You will get the wrong answer with your code in this case.

Better would be:

```
M[[All, 1]][[Position[M[[All, 2]], Max[M[[All, 2]]]][[1, 1]] ]]
```

Or alternatively

```
M[[Position[M[[All, 2]], Max[M[[All, 2]]]][[1, 1]], 1]]
```

Comment: I can't commit to the Mathematica stack, since it is already 100%. Gneh

Answer (score 3):

```
m = {{1, 2}, {3, 1}, {-1, 1}}
max = Max[m[[All, 2]]]
```

So find the position of the max and replace the second column with the first:

```
pos=Position[m, max] /. {x_,_}:>{x,1}
{{1,1}}
```

Then take the first element from pos, i.e. {1,1} and sub use it in `Part`

```
m[[Sequence @@ First[pos]]]
1
```

But having said that I prefer something like this:

```
Cases[m, {x_, max} :> x]
{1}
```

The result is a list. You could either use `First@Cases[...]` or you might want to keep a list of results to cover cases where the maximum value occurs more than once in a column.

Comment: Your version is far more elegant than mine. I was focussed on explaining how `Position` and `Part` worked.

Comment: I started down that route but then decided to do it the way I would do it.

Comment: One of those cases where both answers are worth keeping, then. I wonder which is faster?

Comment: On my machine the timing for this is negligible so I would use `Cases` simply because I like using it :) and find it much easier to read.

Comment: Thanks guys, I did not anticipate such sympathetic and fast answers. I have been reading SO for a while, but I have just registered. Thank you for the nice answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want a single column one value in the case of duplicate maximum values in column two I suggest that you make use of `Ordering`:

```
m = {{1, 3}, {1, 8}, {5, 7}, {2, 2}, {1, 9}, {4, 9}, {5, 6}};

m[[ Ordering[m[[All, 2]], -1], 1 ]]
```

```
{4}
```